# XML Processing Failed in Hadoop

Tags: xml, hadoop, mapreduce

I am really new to this field.
By referring http://java.dzone.com/articles/hadoop-practice i did 
https://github.com/studhadoop/xmlparsing-hadoop/blob/master/XmlParser11.java

and created jar file and then run the mapreduce pgm.
my xml file is

```
<configuration>
    <property>
            <name>dfs.replication</name>
            <value>1</value>
            <type>tr</type>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

and

```
root# javac -classpath /var/root/hadoop-1.0.4/hadoop-core-1.0.4.jar -d xml11 XmlParser11.java

root# jar -cvf /var/root/xmlparser11/xmlparser.jar -C xml11/ .

root# bin/hadoop jar /var/root/xmlparser11/xmlparser.jar com.org.XmlParser11 /user/root/xmlfiles/conf.xml /user/root/xmlfiles-outputjava3
```

UPDATE

```
13/03/30 09:39:58 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
13/03/30 09:39:58 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
13/03/30 09:39:58 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
13/03/30 09:39:58 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
13/03/30 09:39:58 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201303300855_0004
13/03/30 09:39:59 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/03/30 09:40:13 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201303300855_0004_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, recieved java.lang.String
    at com.org.XmlParser11$Map.map(XmlParser11.java:186)
    at com.org.XmlParser11$Map.map(XmlParser11.java:148)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, recieved java.lang.String
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:691)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskInputOutputContext.write(TaskInputOutputContext.java:80)
    at com.org.XmlParser11$Map.map(XmlParser11.java:184)
    ... 9 more

attempt_201303300855_0004_m_000000_0: ‘<property>
attempt_201303300855_0004_m_000000_0:             <name>dfs.replication</name>
attempt_201303300855_0004_m_000000_0:                 <value>1</value>
attempt_201303300855_0004_m_000000_0:             </property>‘
13/03/30 09:40:19 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201303300855_0004_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, recieved java.lang.String
    at com.org.XmlParser11$Map.map(XmlParser11.java:186)
    at com.org.XmlParser11$Map.map(XmlParser11.java:148)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, recieved java.lang.String
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:691)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskInputOutputContext.write(TaskInputOutputContext.java:80)
    at com.org.XmlParser11$Map.map(XmlParser11.java:184)
    ... 9 more

attempt_201303300855_0004_m_000000_1: ‘<property>
attempt_201303300855_0004_m_000000_1:             <name>dfs.replication</name>
attempt_201303300855_0004_m_000000_1:                 <value>1</value>
attempt_201303300855_0004_m_000000_1:             </property>‘
13/03/30 09:40:25 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201303300855_0004_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, recieved java.lang.String
    at com.org.XmlParser11$Map.map(XmlParser11.java:186)
    at com.org.XmlParser11$Map.map(XmlParser11.java:148)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, recieved java.lang.String
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:691)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskInputOutputContext.write(TaskInputOutputContext.java:80)
    at com.org.XmlParser11$Map.map(XmlParser11.java:184)
    ... 9 more

attempt_201303300855_0004_m_000000_2: ‘<property>
attempt_201303300855_0004_m_000000_2:             <name>dfs.replication</name>
attempt_201303300855_0004_m_000000_2:                 <value>1</value>
attempt_201303300855_0004_m_000000_2:             </property>‘
13/03/30 09:40:37 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201303300855_0004
13/03/30 09:40:37 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 7
13/03/30 09:40:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 
13/03/30 09:40:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=27296
13/03/30 09:40:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
13/03/30 09:40:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
13/03/30 09:40:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=4
13/03/30 09:40:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map tasks=4
13/03/30 09:40:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=0
13/03/30 09:40:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Failed map tasks=1
```

what is wrong in map-reduce code? How can i rectify it??

Comment: How do you see that text:null. I see only one System.out.println in the code. And why don't you have a Reducer even though you have configured FileOutputFormat.

Comment: i was also wondering from where it came text:null...edited my code Now prints <configuration> </configuration>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this command and see

```
root# bin/hadoop fs -cat /user/root/xmlfiles-outputjava3/part-r-00000
```

whether you have the desired output. The Output you have specified is the standard output you get when the Map Reduce is running in HDFS.

**UPDATE**

You would need to put System.out.println

```
if (currentElement.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
    propertyName += reader.getText();
    System.out.println(propertyName);
} else if (currentElement.equalsIgnoreCase("value")) {
    propertyValue += reader.getText();
    System.out.println(propertyValue);
}
```

To see the property name and value are being set. If not you need to find why?

**UPDATE 2**

```
context.write(propertyName.trim(), propertyValue.trim());
```

propertyName and propertyValue are String but you have declared your Mapper to output Text as key and value.

Change like this.

```
Text name = new Text();
Text value = new Text();
name.setText(propertyName.trim());
value.setText(propertyValue.trim());
context.write(name, value);
```

Comment: prints <configuration></configuration> the abv map-reduce pgm should print all the xml tags right????

Comment: I added an IOEXCEPTION ..now it shows the adv error Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, recieved java.lang.String

Comment: thx for ur UPDATE 2. it works :) i changed to  context.write(new Text(propertyName.trim()), new Text(propertyValue.trim()));

Comment: i am only able to get name and value .i need type content also.what shld i change in my pgm https://github.com/studhadoop/xmlparsing-hadoop/blob/master/XmlParser11.java

Comment: In my HDFS i will be doing xml processing . ie processing an xml file and extracting 2 nodes.And this will be my x and y to plot a graph.

How can I do this .Generating graph from hdfs output.I want to use Rapid miner.how can i do this any idea...

Answer (score 0):

please use SAX parser or Hadoop Streaming to parse XML.
And Next,for your reference, follow this link.

http://xmlandhadoop.blogspot.in/
http://www.undercloud.org/?p=408

Regards,
Sudhakar Reddy